# How to determine NoSQL data structure (more or fewer collections)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm working with firebase firestore to create a prototype web application.  My goal is to have two different views, unprocessed and processing. Users will be associated with a site, when they login they will only see details associated with their site.  Approach 1, create the following collections:

- sites
- site1Processed
- site1Unprocessed
- site2Processed
- site2Unprocessed

When someone picks a detail from site1Unprocessed it moves it to site1Processed

The second approach is to minimize the collections and use document properties instead, resulting in the following collections:

- sites
- details

the each detail document has a property called site and status.

When a document changes state from unprocessed to processing it will be removed from the unprocessed view. When a document changes state from processing to completed it will not be loaded into any view but will be accessed by reports. In the unprocessed view there are other properties on the details that will update realtime as well.

What factors affect which of these stuctures is more appropriate?

Comment: This sounds like a matter of preference to me, unless you're able to come up with further use cases that make it impossible to work with one or the other choice.  We can't really come up with those use cases for you.  The bottom line for NoSQL data modeling is that your modeling should support the queries you intend to perform.  And sometimes you end up duplicating data in the database in order to support all required queries.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to do it with 2 collections because the queries are far more powerful than I understood when asking the question.

I used this code to get the details:

```
this.unprocessed =  this.firestore.getDetails(this.selectedSite.Name, 'Unprocessed').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    switch (change.type) {
      case 'added':
        this.unprocessedDetails.push(Object.assign(change.doc.data(), { id: change.doc.id }));
        break;
      case 'modified':
        this.updateDetail(this.unprocessedDetails, change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
        break;
      case 'removed':
        this.unprocessedDetails = this.unprocessedDetails.filter(x => x.id !== change.doc.id);
    }
  });
});
```

If a detail is updated and the state is no longer Unprocessed then docChanges is triggered and the detail is removed.  If the detail number of the document changes then docChanges is triggered and the detail can be updated.

The advantage of organizing it this way is that it's easier to find what you're looking for (no need to search multiple collections).